# Is the squeeze theorem still valid when $|b_n| \leq |c_n| \leq |a_n|$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, examples-counterexamples

Reading Körner's *Companion to analysis* there's an exercise that asks whether $c_n \rightarrow c$ is implied if both $a_n \rightarrow c$ and $b_n \rightarrow c$ when $|b_n| \leq |c_n| \leq |a_n|$.

Initially I thought that the implication should be false, since we could have $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ (e.g. when $a_n < 0$ and $0 \leq b_n \leq c_n$), i.e. it could be that the sequence $\{c_n\}$ is not "squeezed" by $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$. **But I struggle to find an example.**

However, if we are to have that $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ and $|b_n| \leq |c_n| \leq |a_n|$, then **I think** we need to have $|c_n - b_n| < |a_n - b_n|$, which will imply that $c_n \rightarrow c$.

Could you help me either

1. Find example sequences such that $a_n \leq b_n \leq c_n$ and $|b_n| \leq |c_n| \leq |a_n|$, where $a_n \rightarrow c$ and $b_n \rightarrow c$ but $c_n \nrightarrow c$.
2. Or comment whether my argument above, using $|c_n - b_n| < |a_n - b_n|$, is correct.

Comment: For a counterexample, just take any $c<0$, and set $a_n=b_n=c$ for all $n$, and $c_n=-c$ for all $n$.

Comment: Right, so $a_n = b_n = c$, $c_n = -c$, which takes advantage of the fact that there are no strict inequalities in the assumption that $|b_n| \leq |c_n| \leq |a_n|$. This was quite obvious, and I now feel rather stupid!

Comment: Is there another example which can serve as a counterexample when $|b_n| < |c_n| < |a_n|$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ to be constant sequence, say $1$ and $\{c_n\}$ alternates between $1$ and $-1$. This serves as a counter example to the said claim.